# how to iterate each file inside a variable in makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to create *.o for each cpp file inside variable "CPPS" (in Ubuntu)

```
CPPS := file1.cpp \                
        file2.cpp \
        file3.cpp \
        folder1/file4.cpp \
        folder2/file5.cpp \
        folder2/folder21/file6.cpp 

OBJS := file1.o \                
        file2.o \
        file3.o \
        file4.o \
        file5.o \
        file6.o  


test:$(OBJS)
    $(CXX)  $(FLAG) -o m $(OBJS)
```

I want to create *.o for each cpp automatically. And I want to create *.o inside the same folder of Makefile. 
If all the cpps are in the same folder as Makefile, we can use

```
%.o:%.cpp
    $(CXX)  $(FLAG) -c -o $@ $< $(INC)
```

But the problem is they are in different folders, currently I have to write a script to create a lnk for each file. Is there a way to iterator over each file inside a variable? or it there an another way to do that?

Comment: Why are you overriding  the built-in rule for cpp files with one that uses the C compiler (`$(CC)`) instead of the C++ compiler (`$(CXX)`)?

Comment: Thanks! I have changed it to CXX

Comment: how about using `${CPPS:.cpp=.o}`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question why you're overriding the perfectly good built-in rule for cpp files.

Comment: Wait... where do you want the object files (`file6.o`)? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Beta I update the question. I want to create *.o for each cpp automatically.  And I want to create *.o inside the same folder of Makefile.

Comment: @melpomene sorry, I didn't get it. What do you mean the "perfectly good built-in rule" here ?

Comment: Which make-variant do you use? If BSD make your desire would be very simple.

Comment: @uzsolt in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @camino: so GNU make?

Comment: @uzsolt yes. GNU Make 4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using source files in different directories is what [the `vpath` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search) is for:

```
CPPS := file1.cpp ...
OBJS := file1.o ...

vpath %.cpp folder1 folder2 folder2/folder21

all: $(OBJS)
```

And you can generate the vpath and OBJS from CPPS, rather than typing them all in by hand:

```
CPPS := file1.cpp ...
OBJS := $(notdir $(CPPS:.cpp=.o))

SRCDIRS := $(dir $(CPPS))
vpath %.cpp $(SRCDIRS)

all: $(OBJS)
```

Comment: If you use `SRCDIRS := $(sort $(dir $(CPPS))` you can avoid adding duplicates to `VPATH`, because `sort` also uniqifies.

Comment: I've deleted my answer so that OP doesn't get distracted and focuses on the `vpath` approach.

Comment: @MadScientist: Yes, and we can also remove "./", but remember that we're talking about tidying up a list that no human being has to see.

Comment: @Beta true that it's not visible to people, but it's visible to make.  If you have 200 source files and you add 200 `./` to your vpath, make will search the current directory 200 times before it moves on to look in the next directory.  That will be noticeable, for a larger build system...